# Is there a way to set labels for Subscription of Google Pub/Sub which is Push delivery type?

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

I want to set the labels on (push) Subscriptions to be able to differentiate the cost of each service.

When I try add label on console I got the message 'Unable to save labels'.
Then I try to verify the domain using HTML meta tag but got the following error message.
"INVALID_ARGUMENT: The supplied HTTP URL is not registered in the subscription's parent project."

Is there a way to verify domain which url in this format 
https://{hash}-dot-{hash}.appspot.com/_ah/push-handlers/pubsub/projects/{project-id}/topics/{topic-id}?pubsub_trigger=true ?

I am able to verify domain using HTML meta tag which url in this format 
https://us-central1-.cloudfunctions.net/ well.

I just wonder do I really need to verify push subscription endpoint domain to be able to add the labels to push subscription?

```
gcloud pubsub subscriptions update subscription_name --update-labels env=dev --push-endpoint=https://hashA-dot-hashB-tp.appspot.com/_ah/push-handlers/pubsub/projects/project_id/topics/topic_id?pubsub_trigger=true
```

Answer (score 0):

This subscription that you are trying to modify is managed by Cloud Functions, which means you will not be able to set its labels.

Comment: any alternative way to monitor cost for push subscription on billing then?